How to make a delete button to delete an item, to which it belongs, from the list?
Sorry for my English.I have an array of items, that are being rendered on my web-page. Each item has a delete button, but how can I anchor a click on a button to the item, that it(button) belongs to? I mean: how can I delete exactly that item, which button I clicked? Do I need to add IDs to my items, if so, how can I do that?
Preferably without server or React, just JS
Looking forward for your help!
From my CodePen
HTML
<section class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="mb-3">Details storage</h2>
    <form class="mb-3" action="" id="add-detail">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input required class='form-control' type="number" placeholder="Detail Code" id="input-key">
        </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input required class='form-control' type="text" placeholder="Category" id="input-category">
        </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input required class='form-control' type="number" placeholder="Amount" id="input-amount">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input required class='form-control' type="number" placeholder="Price per piece" id="input-price">
        </div>
      <button class='btn btn-primary'>Add</button>
    </form>
    <table class="table table-striped detailsTable">
      <thead>
      <th data-column="key">Detail Code</th>
      <th data-column="category">Category</th>
      <th data-column="amount">Amount</th>
      <th data-column="price">Price per piece</th>
      <th data-column="totalPrice">Total amount</th> 
      <th></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="details-list">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div> 
</section>

JS
class Detail {
  constructor(key, category, amount, price) {
    this.key=key
    this.category=category
    this.amount=amount
    this.price=price
  }
  get totalPrice() {
    return (this.amount * this.price);
}
}

const details=[
  new Detail(0,'Nails',300,4),
  new Detail(1,'Screws',400,6),
  new Detail(2,'Bolts',600,5),
  new Detail(3,'Self-tapping screw',700,3),
  new Detail(4,'Nails', 400, 2)
]

const $detailsList = document.getElementById('details-list'),
      $detailsListTHALL = document.querySelectorAll('.detailsTable th')

let column = 'key',
    columnDir = true

function newDetailTR(detail){
  const $detailTR= document.createElement('tr'),
        $keyTD= document.createElement('td'),
        $categoryTD= document.createElement('td'),
        $amountTD= document.createElement('td'),
        $priceTD= document.createElement('td'),
        $totalPriceTD=document.createElement('td'),
        $deleteTD=document.createElement('button')
  
  $keyTD.textContent=detail.key
  $categoryTD.textContent=detail.category
  $amountTD.textContent=detail.amount
  $priceTD.textContent=detail.price
  $totalPriceTD.textContent = detail.totalPrice
  $deleteTD.textContent="Delete"
  
  $detailTR.append($keyTD)
  $detailTR.append($categoryTD)
  $detailTR.append($amountTD)
  $detailTR.append($priceTD)
  $detailTR.append($totalPriceTD)
  $detailTR.append($deleteTD)
  
  return $detailTR;
}


function getSortDetails(prop, dir) {
  const detailsCopy=[...details]
  return detailsCopy.sort(function(detailA, detailB){
    if((!dir==false? detailA[prop] <detailB[prop] : detailA[prop] > detailB[prop])) return -1;
  })
}

function render(){
  let detailsCopy=[...details];
  
  detailsCopy=getSortDetails(column, columnDir);
  
  $detailsList.innerHTML = '';
  for(const detail of detailsCopy){
    $detailsList.append(newDetailTR(detail))
  }
}


$detailsListTHALL.forEach(elment => {
  elment.addEventListener('click', function() {
    column = this.dataset.column;
    columnDir = !columnDir;
    render()
  })
})


document.getElementById('add-detail').addEventListener('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  details.push(new Detail(
    Number(document.getElementById('input-key').value),
    document.getElementById('input-category').value,
    Number(document.getElementById('input-amount').value),
    Number(document.getElementById('input-price').value)
  ))
  
  render()
  alert('Item has been added!')
  event.preventDefault();
  event.target.reset(); 
})

render()


try adding a click event handler to the $deleteTD you created dynamically for each row. Then inside the event callback given its signature as (event)=>{...} you may determine the parent of the clicked delete button by doing event.target.closest('tr')

When you create your TR element, assign a click to it; basically like this (by using a reusable function elNew to create new DOM elements):
const $detailTR = elNew('tr')
const $deleteButton = elNew('button', {
  textContent: "Delete",
  onclick() {
    removeDetail(detail); // Remove from array
    $detailTR.remove();   // Remove from HTML
  }
});

also, don't forget to:

create a TD wrapper for your delete button
don't clone your arrays, otherwise you'll not be able to keep track of the item index to delete (after you sort the array)

Example:


// DOM utility functions:
const el = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelectorAll(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

class Detail {
  constructor(key, category, amount, price) {
    this.key = key;
    this.category = category;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.price = price;
  }
  get totalPrice() {
    return (this.amount * this.price);
  }
}

const details = [
  new Detail(0, 'Nails', 300, 4),
  new Detail(1, 'Screws', 400, 6),
  new Detail(2, 'Bolts', 600, 5),
  new Detail(3, 'Self-tapping screw', 700, 3),
  new Detail(4, 'Wheels', 400, 2),
];

const $detailsList = el('#details-list');
const $detailsListTHALL = els('.detailsTable th');

let column = 'key';
let columnDir = true;

function removeDetail(detail) {
  const index = details.indexOf(detail);
  if (index > -1) details.splice(index, 1);
}

function newDetailTR(detail) {
  const $detailTR = elNew('tr'),
        $keyTD = elNew('td', { textContent: detail.key }),
        $categoryTD = elNew('td', { textContent: detail.category }),
        $amountTD = elNew('td', { textContent: detail.amount }),
        $priceTD = elNew('td', { textContent: detail.price }),
        $totalPriceTD = elNew('td', { textContent: detail.totalPrice }),
        $deleteTD = elNew('td'),
        $deleteButton = elNew('button', {
          textContent: "Delete",
          onclick() {
            removeDetail(detail); // Remove from array
            $detailTR.remove();   // Remove from HTML
          }
        });
  $deleteTD.append($deleteButton);
  $detailTR.append($keyTD, $categoryTD, $amountTD, $priceTD, $totalPriceTD, $deleteTD);
  return $detailTR;
}

function getSortDetails(prop, dir) {
  return details.sort(function(a, b) {
    if((!dir==false? a[prop] < b[prop] : a[prop] > b[prop])) return -1;
  });
}

function render() {
  const detailsCopy = getSortDetails(column, columnDir);
  $detailsList.innerHTML = "";
  details.forEach(detail => $detailsList.append(newDetailTR(detail)));
}

el('#add-detail').addEventListener('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  details.push(new Detail(
    el('#input-key').valueAsNumber,
    el('#input-category').value,
    el('#input-amount').valueAsNumber,
    el('#input-price').valueAsNumber
  ));

  render();
  event.target.reset(); 
})

render();
  <section class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="mb-3">Details storage</h2>
    <form class="mb-3" action="" id="add-detail">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input required class='form-control' type="number" placeholder="Detail Code" id="input-key">
        </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input required class='form-control' type="text" placeholder="Category" id="input-category">
        </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input required class='form-control' type="number" placeholder="Amount" id="input-amount">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input required class='form-control' type="number" placeholder="Price per piece" id="input-price">
        </div>
      <button class='btn btn-primary'>Add</button>
    </form>
    <table class="table table-striped detailsTable">
      <thead>
        <th data-column="key">Detail Code</th>
        <th data-column="category">Category</th>
        <th data-column="amount">Amount</th>
        <th data-column="price">Price per piece</th>
        <th data-column="totalPrice">Total amount</th> 
        <th></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="details-list"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div> 
</section>




Roko C. Buljan, thank you for your help!!!
